# What would happen when two wave functions intersect in a Fourier series representation of periodic signals?

Tags: waves, astronomy, fourier-transform, oscillators, signal-processing

I saw a piece of code on github which transforms the planetary movement into the fourier wave function.

These circles are given by the x and y ordinates: x=cos(ωt) y=sin(ωt), which are periodic. Usually, we can apply it to get the frequency components - spectrum of the signal as @Brendan Darrer suggest. Which is a very useful concept, when talking about electromagnetic signal for example. However, when we step further and have a closer look about the intersection the plot below gives us, what can we interpret from these intersection points.

To help us see this question more clearly, we can imagine it as a star system just like our solar system. As we can see visually in the plot below, there are four wave functions in the plot. Though they have the different frequency (rotation period), they will intersect at specific time. At the intersection of two wave functions,say, 4sin(3θ)/3pi and 4sin(5θ)/5pi, it suggests that these two planets will have the same phase at their orbit and have the same projected displacement (same y value) mathematically. My question is, what would happen when two wave functions intersect in a Fourier series representation of periodic signals?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by intersection?

Comment: I am referring to the intersections we can see visually in the plot above. There are four wave functions in the plot and they have the different frequency. They will intersect at specific time. But that's just the mathematical meaning, and I want to know what the physical meaning of this intersection is? @ProfRob

Comment: didn’t you ask a nearly identical question yesterday?

Comment: I've deleted my answer. Can you explain how two planets can have the same projected displacement at the same value of $\theta$, if $\theta \neq 0$?

Comment: @ProfRob One particular example that comes to mind is the Eastern or Western quadrature. At this point, the Earth and the planets will have the same projected displacement. But the intersection in the intersection conceptual model could be more general than this example.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, the question has some conceptual mistake (this conceptual model cannot be applied to atoms) and have been deleted and resubmitted. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin in such cases better to edit the old question…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, you're right. As it is my first time to post, I would keep in mind to avoid it next time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by eastern and western quadrature. If you mean $\theta = \pi/2$ or $3\pi/2$ then no, the planets cannot have the same projected displacement as seen from the Earth at those angles.  They can only have the same projected distance at multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @ProfRob I mean the eastern quadrature in spherical astronomy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_(astronomy). Assuming the orange line is earth, the red line is Mars.

Answer (score 1):

These circles are given by the $x$ and $y$ ordinates: $x = cos(\omega t)$ $y = sin(\omega t)$, which are periodic. If talking about anything, electromagnetic signal, acoustic pressure etc, one can apply a Fourier transform and get the frequency components - spectrum of the signal. Which is a very useful concept, when talking about electromagnetic signal for example. In this case, instead of guessing which frequencies are present in your complex signal, by looking to the spectrum you can see it immediately.

You can check for example youtube videos on the spectrum analyzers, in order to see the application for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I knew the fourier transform, but what about the intersection of two wave functions in the plot. What would happen when two wave functions intersect in a Fourier series representation of periodic signals? @Pierre Polovodov

Comment: @Kevin, what do you mean for intersection? Do you mean two wave functions with the same frequency or different frequency, do you consider the same phase?

Comment: I am referring to the intersections we can see visually in the plot above. There are four wave functions in the plot and they have the different frequency. But they will intersect when they share the same y values. But that's just the mathematical meaning, and I want to know what the physical meaning of this intersection is? @Pierre Polovodov

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, there are four functions describing the objects orbits and there is a blue curve with a frequency $f$, the red one $2f$, the other ones are multiples of $f$. The thing is that, the curves will intersect when the phases are equal, for exemple $2\pi f t + 2 \pi= 2\pi 2 f t$ etc.

Comment: yes, it is. I want to confirm if it suggests that their phases are equal when intersect and what would happen when intersect. Will the intersection cause phase shift?

Comment: Phase shift is the difference between phases. When curves intersect they have the phase shift of $2 \pi n$ where $ n \in \mathbb{Z}$ And the point is that the pulsation $\omega = 2 \pi f$ gives different phase after a certain time. For different phase numbers the phase changes in a different way but when the phase shift reaches $2 \p ni$ you have the initial condition. By the way you start when all the phases are equal in the beginning (or they difference is $2 \pi n$, but it does not change a thing), another situation will appear when phase shift is a different value.